# How to handle decimal numbers in solidity?

Tags: solidity

How to handle decimal numbers in solidity?
If you want to find the percentage of some amount and do some calculation on that number, how to do that?

Suppose I perform : 15 % of 45 and need to divide that value with 7 how to get the answer.

Please help. I have done research, but getting answer like it is not possible to do that calculation. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options. To just multiply by a percentage (but truncate to an integer result), `45 * 15 / 100 = 6` works well. (45 * 15%)

If you want to keep some more digits around, you can just scale everything up by, e.g., some exponent of 10. `4500 * 15 / 100 = 675` (i.e. 6.75 * 100).

Comment: So how to get the final answer. 675 will be stored there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just store 675. If you're asking how to display something like "6.75" in UI, just divide by 100 (e.g. in JavaScript on a web page or wherever you're building such UI).